# cors issue when accessing mapbox from localhost

Tags: cors, mapbox-gl-js

I get the following message while testing a simple mapbox example on my local machine (served with python SimpleHTTPServer on port localhost:8000):

`10:06:53.909 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/[...]. (Reason: CORS request failed).1 <unknown>`

The html file is straightfoward:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.17.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.17.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = <myaccesstoken>;
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8', //stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am viewing from Firefox, have tried disabling CORS policy, I am losing faith, gosh it should be so simple ! Any help greatly appreciated !

EDIT : getting the same issue if I am calling mapzen or osm2vectortile service, so mapbox is not the problem, seems like a generic cors issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add this header in the first line of the doc, above < !DOCTYPE html >:

`<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>`